# Cause of ORA-00604/ORA-00942 error when executing stored procedured included in package from VB6

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, vb6

I am dealing with a problem calling a stored procedure contained in a package from VB6.

First, as a test of my implementation, I created a standalone stored procedure. After confirming that the correct users/roles were granted the execute privilege on the procedure, I was able to successfully run the procedure and display the contents of reference cursor that was returned.

I then moved this procedure into an oracle package.

After granting (what I believe are) the appropriate privileges to the users/roles required, I am able to execute this procedure from SQL Developer and directly from SQLPlus. However, when I got to execute the procedure from VB6 using the same method that I used to execute the standalone procedure I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '-2147217900(80040e14)':

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I am confused as to what the error means since I am able to execute the procedure from SQL Developer and SQLPlus.

What is the cause of the error and are there any steps that I'm missing in debugging this error?

For reference here is the code for my package header and my package body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE random_package AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS

    --------------------------------------------------------
    -- procedure headers
    --------------------------------------------------------
    PROCEDURE random_procedure( 
        variable1 IN VARCHAR,
        variable2 IN VARCHAR,
        variable3 IN VARCHAR,
        variable4 IN VARCHAR,
        variable5 IN VARCHAR,
        variable6 IN VARCHAR,
        output_reference_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    );

END random_package;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY random_package AS

    --------------------------------------------------------
    -- constants
    --------------------------------------------------------

    --------------------------------------------------------
    -- procedure headers
    --------------------------------------------------------
    PROCEDURE random_procedure( 
        variable1 IN VARCHAR,
        variable2 IN VARCHAR,
        variable3 IN VARCHAR,
        variable4 IN VARCHAR,
        variable5 IN VARCHAR,
        variable6 IN VARCHAR,
        output_reference_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    ) IS
    BEGIN
        OPEN output_reference_cursor FOR
            SELECT 
                i.prod_item_id, 
                i.prod_item_partnr, 
                i.prod_item_fname, 
                rh.random_quantity, 
                round(variable1 / rh.random_quantity * base_quantity, 0) as isuQty, 
                i.ITEM_UNIT_ID, 
                i.PROD_ITEM_CTRL
            FROM 
                vm_recipe_hdr rh, 
                vm_recipe r, 
                vm_prod_item i, 
                vm_prod_type t, 
                vmm_prodtype_scrn pts
            WHERE 
                rh.PROD_ITEM_ID = variable2
                AND rh.PROD_ITEM_ID = r.PROD_ITEM_ID
                AND i.prod_item_id = r.PROD_ITEM_ID_SUB 
                AND t.PROD_TYPE_ID = i.PROD_TYPE_ID 
                AND pts.PROD_TYPE_SCRN = t.PROD_TYPE_SCRN 
                AND pts.PRODTYPE_SCRN_SYS = variable3
                AND pts.PROD_TYPE_SCRN not in (variable4, variable5) 
                AND i.PROD_ITEM_CTRL = variable6
            ;

        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                ROLLBACK;
    END random_procedure;

END random_package;
```

Comment: Qualify tables in `FROM` with schema (e.g. `schema_name.vm_recipe_hdr rh`), or don't use `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` , or create public synonyms for tables involved)

Comment: Removing AUTHID CURRENT_USER solved the problem. Kudos.

Comment: @a1ex07 Thanks for the answer to the question. Would it be possible for you to post the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` means that package will be executed with current user credential (the user who executes procedures/functions in the package). However, it seems that the creator of the package (and the owner of objects used inside) is different from the user who executes procedure. Thus, the engine searches for tables such as `vm_recipe_hdr, vm_recipe, etc` in current user's schema, not in creator's schema.

I can think about three ways the problem can be resolved.

1. Public synonyms for tables. Not an elegant solution , has hidden performance pitfalls - (e.g. plans won't be shared for 2 different users (extra hard parse)).
2. Remove `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` - by default Oracle executes subprograms with creator credentials ; consequently object names will be resolved in creator schema)
3. Qualify each object explicitly (for instance, `schema_name.vm_recipe_hdr`)